# Does Allure handle xfail, xpass, skip, and error from pytest?

Tags: pytest, allure

From the front page of https://allurereport.org/, it looks like these categories are created:

- Pending
- Passed
- Canceled
- Broken
- Failed

How does this map to pytest categories?
I'd like to see **skipped**, **xpass**, **xfail**, and **error**.

Are they supported?
If so, what is the mapping to allure categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not yet explicitly documented, but **pytest-allure-adaptor** of version `1.5.4` converts pytest's statuses to their allure counterparts as follows:

- `PASSED` => `PASSED`
- `FAILED` => `FAILED`
- `SKIPPED` => `CANCELLED`
- `ERROR` => `BROKEN`
- `xfail` => `PENDING`
- `XPASS` => `FAILED`  (because allure has no special status for that)